# Why does getting my access token work in Postman but not in my code?

Tags: c#, oauth-2.0, identityserver4

I have implemented Identity Server 4 to for OAuth authentication and it is working fine when I make an authentication request in Postman (I recieve my AccessToken, Token Type, id_token, expires_in etc) and can use the access token to access my protected api.  However, when I try to do this in code I end up with an error 'invalid_grant'.

Why is this working in Postman but not when I make the calls in code?

My process is as follows:

1. An api call is made to set the patient context by saving the patient id and a GUID to the database.  The Guid is my 'launch' value.
2. I call a custom /auth endpoint as it requires the extra parameter ('launch') that is used maintain context ( the id value of a patient ) passing in all of the required parameters for the ID4 /connect/authorize/

   eg. https://IDS4.azurewebsites.net/auth2?client_id=client&response_type=code&scope=openid
   profile myAPI&client_secret=secret&state=1234567890p&aud=https://api.location.com&launch=K123K456Y7777&redirect_uri=https://test.azurewebsites.net/auth

   This endpoint will associate the value of 'state' with 'launch' in the database to maintain context.
3. The above endpoint then calls the IDS4 /connect/authorize/ endpoint, passing in the appropriate values.  In the auth pipeline I then associate 'sessionId' with 'state' again to maintain context.
4. The IDS4 /connect/authorize/ endpoint returns the authorization code, scope, state and session_state as expected.
5. Within the Get of the redirectURI specified in the 'authorize' call above, I take the authorization code and execute a standard post to the ID4 /connect/token endpoint.
6. The response is 'invalid_grant'

All of this works in Postman.

I have tried changing around the AllowedGrantTypes of my client but I think 'authorization_code' is the one to stick with.  I use the GrantTypes enum.
The following is my Client config:

```
            new Client
            {
                ClientId = "client",
                ClientSecrets = { new Secret("secret".Sha256()) },

                //RequireClientSecret = false, //false is default

                RequirePkce = false, //to prevent 'code challenge required' message from appearing when using 'Code'

                AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.Code ,//{ "code", "authorization_code" },// 
                
                // where to redirect to after login
                RedirectUris = { "https://IDS4.azurewebsites.net/signin-oidc", "https://test.azurewebsites.net/auth",
                "https://test.azurewebsites.net/token", "https://IDS4.azurewebsites.net/Account/Login"  },

                // where to redirect to after logout
                PostLogoutRedirectUris = { "https://IDS4.azurewebsites.net/signout-callback-oidc" },

                AllowedScopes = new List<string>
                {
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.OpenId,
                    IdentityServerConstants.StandardScopes.Profile,   
                    "myAPI"
                }
            }
```

My Startup code:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddControllersWithViews();

        services.AddDbContextPool<AppDbContext>(options =>
                options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DBConnection")));

        var builder = services.AddIdentityServer()
            .AddInMemoryIdentityResources(Config.IdentityResources)
            .AddInMemoryApiScopes(Config.ApiScopes)
            .AddInMemoryClients(Config.Clients)
            .AddTestUsers(TestUsers.Users)
            .AddCustomTokenRequestValidator<CustomTokenRequestValidator>()
            .AddCustomAuthorizeRequestValidator<CustomAuthorizeRequestValidator>();
        

        builder.AddDeveloperSigningCredential();

        services.AddAuthentication()
            .AddGoogle("Google", options =>
            {
                options.SignInScheme = IdentityServerConstants.ExternalCookieAuthenticationScheme;

                options.ClientId = "<insert here>";
                options.ClientSecret = "<insert here>";
            });

        
        services.AddMvc()
            .SetCompatibilityVersion(CompatibilityVersion.Version_3_0).AddXmlSerializerFormatters()
            .AddMvcOptions(options => options.EnableEndpointRouting = false);

        services.AddScoped<IDebugRepository, SQLDebugRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IPatientContextRepository, SQLPatientContextRepository>();
        services.AddScoped<IClinicAccessRepository, SQLClinicAccessRepository>();
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseCookiePolicy(new CookiePolicyOptions
        {
            HttpOnly = HttpOnlyPolicy.None,
            MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None,
            Secure = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
        });

        app.UseStaticFiles();
        app.UseRouting();

        app.UseIdentityServer();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapDefaultControllerRoute();
        });

    }
```

This is how I make the POST to the /connect/Token endpoint within the Auth Get:

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<string> Get(string code, string scope, string state, string session_state)
        {

        try
        {
            //AuthResponseModel arm = new AuthResponseModel
            //{
            //    code = code,
            //    scope = scope,
            //    state = state,
            //    session_state = session_state
            //};

            string grant_type = "authorization_code";
            string redirect_uri = "https://test.azurewebsites.net/token"; //sends the token back to requestor
            string client_id = "client"; //current stable testing client
            string baseAddress = $"https://IDS4.azurewebsites.net/connect/token";
            string client_secret = "secret";

            var client = new HttpClient();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri($"https://IDS4.azurewebsites.net/");
            var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
            {
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_id", client_id),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("client_secret", client_secret),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", grant_type),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("code", code),
                new KeyValuePair<string, string>("redirect_uri", redirect_uri)
              });

            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/x-www-form-urlencoded"));

            var res = await client.PostAsync(baseAddress, content);
            var resp = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            return resp;

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return  ex.Message + Environment.NewLine + ex.StackTrace ;
        }
    }
```

One thing I have not tried is setting a signing certificate.  I think Postman using an internal cert that I need to accept but it's been so long I can't quite recall if I did that or not.  I would think that a missing cert would have been causing me problems before now but it's something I'm looking into.

Also, just a note - I have tested the Token redirect and it is working.

Here it is:

```
[Controller]
[Route("Token")]
[AllowAnonymous]
public class TokenController : Controller
{

    [HttpPost]
    public string Post([FromForm] string access_token,
                        [FromForm] string token_type,
                        [FromForm] string expires_in,
                        [FromForm] string scope,
                        [FromForm] string patient,
                        [FromForm] string id_token,
                        [FromForm] string oceanSharedEncryptionKey)
    {
        TokenResponseModel token = new TokenResponseModel
        {
            access_token = access_token,
            expires_in = expires_in,
            id_token = id_token,
            patient = patient,
            scope = scope,
            token_type = token_type
        };
        string rslt = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(token);
        return rslt;
    }

    public string Get( string test1)
    {
        return test1;
    }
}
```

Comment: When you are using postman, what Grant Type you are using for token?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the grant type.
Here you can find the documentation for your case -
https://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/grant_types.html

I have the similar implementation where I use Client credentials in postman and password in the code. you can try the password in postman too

```
private async Task<string> GetNewAccessTokenAsync()
        {
            var postMessage = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
                {"client_id", "Client ID goes here"},
                {"client_secret","Client secret goes here" },
                {"scope","User.Read" },

                {"grant_type", "password"},
                {"username", "Username goes here"},
                {"password", "Password goes here"}

        };

          

            var client1 = new HttpClient();
            var response = await client1.PostAsync("https://login.microsoftonline.com/{{id}}/oauth2/v2.0/token", new FormUrlEncodedContent(postMessage));

            // return response.ReasonPhrase;
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
              

                return json.Result;
            }
            return "";
            
        }
```

Please mark the answer if it is useful to you.

Comment: As you can see in my code snippet I am passing in the grant_type of 'authorization_code'.  It looks like your solution is using the client_credentials flow whereas mine is using authorization.  Instead of username/password the authorization code is passed in.

Comment: Can you please post the logs here.